# Storing resolved service in HttpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am refactoring a MVC application to use dependency injection with Microsoft Unity.

Now I have the problem that there are a lot of calls like this in the Views:

```
@Localize.Html(Text.SomeEnumValueHere)
```

`Localize` is a helper class, `Html()` is a static method that returns a localized `IHtmlString` that is being drawn from the HttpContext.Cache or the database (if not cached yet). `Text` is an enum.

The method looks something like this (not really the code, but a simplified version):

```
public class Localize
{
    public static IHtmlString Html(string key)
    {
        var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        var html = StaticCache.GetHtml(culture, key);
        if(html == null)
        {
             html = new LocalizationDbService().LoadHtml(culture, key);
             StaticCache.StoreHtml(culture, key, html);
        }
        return html;
    }
}
```

So basically all plaintext in the views comes from this type of call to allow multilanguage support.

Because the `Localize` class is dependent on another service that calls the database, it would make sense to use dependency injection here. I am just not sure how to refactor this so I don't have to change every instance of this call in all the Views.

My first idea was to make the method non-static and inject an instance of the `Localize`-class into the controller, which then passes it on to the view through the Model.

This looks like the cleanest approach, however that would mean

- I need to include the `Localize`-object in *every* ViewModel.
- I have to change all the calls to something like `@Model.Localize.Html()`

My second idea was to simply store a `Localize` instance in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection and retrieve it from there in the static call.

This would then look something like

```
public class Localize
{
    public static IHtmlString Html(Text key)
    {
        return (HttpContext.Current.Items["Localize"] as Localize).NonStaticHtml(Key);
    }

    ...
}
```

This way I could keep all the calls like they are, and keep the Localize class out of the controllers and viewmodels to prevent clutter.

1. Is this a good approach or am I perverting the whole idea of IoC/DI?
2. At which point in the application would I store a new Localize object in the HttpContext and how would I resolve it with Unity?

My best guess would be that `Application_BeginRequest` in Global.asax would be the right point, but I would really appreciate input on this whole thing.

Comment: Where is the dependency is `Localize`? I only see `HttpContext`...

Comment: That's not the class how it currently looks, just how I would implement the second approach. The dependencies are in the current (non-DI) implementation of Localize.Html() where the db service is called. I would include it in the question but it includes a lot of irrelevant code. Maybe I will cut it down and edit it in.